# GIMP - Search/filter single brush inside brush panel?

Tags: gimp

I am working with gimp-2.8, when we try to change Brush, we need to scroll all brushes or we can filter by group. Problem is that when we filter by group we can select only one group, and it takes too much loading when we filter/remove-filter(though I did not added additional brushes, except that comes default with gimp). Also it needs to remove filter first and then it will allow to add new filter. Is there any way to change this behaviour or any way to search by brush name? (Note: Filter here means not filter programs, but to filter out Brushes.)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Brushes dialog from a raster view to a List view, then you can hit Ctrl+f and type a brush name. This expects the whole name and not a part of it, though, so you won't get a filter per se.

I couldn't get this to work in the popup you get from the button in e.g. the Paint tool options, so I guess this isn't available there.